# Workbench: Does importing delete new record?

Tags: mysql, workbench

I accidentally deleted some records, but I have backup before the deletion happened. When I import the data coming from my phpMyAdmin, it deleted some records.

**Steps**

```
1. In my phpMyAdmin, I used the search then click the export(in the bottom part)
2. Import the extracted file to workbench
```

Question: When importing in workbench, is it deleting all the record then import or is it just import?

Comment: That depends on what your dump contains. As you haven't shared it, we cannot answer the question properly

Answer (score 0):

1. If you import data set from phpmyadmin it will never delete your data in workbench.
2. But if you import prepared query and run it, make sure there is no
   delete query.
3. Update can also clear data, like if you give condition
   to make empty certain where clause.

Example: Make sure nothing is there like this "update table set fieldname = '' where another_fieldname = 'something' "